# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not recognize attached thermal printer via ethernet

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, printing, ethernet, epson

I bought an EPSON TM-T82 thermal printer. I wanted to connect it to my Ubuntu to use it. I have connected it to my laptop's ethernet port.

Now the printer should show up in the wired connections list. But it is not showing up at all. It is trying to connect to printer but it is not able to connect. It is always showing "Connecting...".

```
$ lpinfo -v
network ipps 
network https
network ipp
network ipp14
network socket
network lpd
network http
network smb
```

Do I have to set up anything to make it work? Anything to be installed? I will add more details if required.

Answer (score 0):

Epson makes a Linux driver. You can get it from [here](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5012&scat=32&pcat=52). It comes down as `tmx-cups-2.0.3.0.tar.gz`.

Assuming you download and SAVE it in your `Downloads` folder:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Copy each line below an paste it in a terminal. Hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each paste.

   ```
   cd Downloads
   tar -zxvf tmx-cups-2.0.3.0.tar.gz
   cd tmx-cups
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```

That should install the drivers and get it working. Do let us know if it works.

Comment: I have installed it. But its not recognising at all. Its not showing up in my wired connections list.